# Payfast API 401 error C#. Merchant authorization failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, md5, payfast

I am currently trying to Ping the Payfast API to get basic authentication rate.

I am stuck at getting the signature correct I think.

To generate the signature I am

Sorting all variables in alphabetical order as seen here and URLencoding

```
string signature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode($"merchant-id={merchantID}&passphrase=​{passphrase}&timestamp={timestamp}&version={version}");
```

I am then generating the MD5 hash string as seen here

```
using (var md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
    // Byte array representation of source string
    var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
    
    // Generate hash value(Byte Array) for input data
    var hashBytes = md5Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);

    // Convert hash byte array to string
    var hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    // Output the MD5 hash
    Console.WriteLine(signature + " is: " + hash);
    string hashlower = hash.ToLower()
}
```

I then add the signature to the header

```
request.AddHeader("merchant-id", merchantID);
request.AddHeader("version", version);
request.AddHeader("signature", hashlower);
request.AddHeader("timestamp", timestamp);
```

This seems correct when viewing an example in their postman collection
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10608852/TVCmSQZu

Could anyone pick anything up that I am doing wrong in the signature generation

ull code

```
string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string signature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode($"merchant-id={merchantID}&passphrase=​{passphrase}&timestamp={timestamp}&version={version}");

using (var md5Hash = MD5.Create())
{
    // Byte array representation of source string
    var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);

    // Generate hash value(Byte Array) for input data
    var hashBytes = md5Hash.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);

    // Convert hash byte array to string
    var hash = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    // Output the MD5 hash
    Console.WriteLine(signature + " is: " + hash);
    string hashlower = hash.ToLower();

    var client = new RestClient("https://api.payfast.co.za/ping");
    client.Timeout = -1;

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("merchant-id", merchantID);
    request.AddHeader("version", version);
    request.AddHeader("signature", hashlower);
    request.AddHeader("timestamp", timestamp);
              
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
```

Comment: Link to payfast documentation https://developers.payfast.co.za/api#authentication

Comment: Really? #C? Really?

Comment: Did you come right with this? I can not find a solution to this. Documentation is really bad

Answer (score 0):

I took the API Documentation and converted line by line matching everything, after copying, and running their   [Node.js](https://replit.com/languages/nodejs) and [Python](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) sample code.

Two things came out in my findings.

***URL Encoding.***

When you URL Encode in c#, eg your date: 
**2023-02-20T20:00:00** becomes **2023-02-20T20%3a00%3a00**

PayFast from Python and Node.js Encode as Uppercase, so: 
**2023-02-20T20:00:00** becomes **2023-02-20T20%3A00%3A00**

Notice the **'A'** in the latter instance, ensure your URL encoding is correct.

 Use `Uri.EscapeDataString([string])`

***Hash Encoding:***

You are assuming that the Encoding is using UTF-8 in c# is the same the Crypto hashing from Node.js and Python, which is in fact ASCII after spending time going through all the variations. Update the following:

```
var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
```

to the following:

```
var sourceBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signature);
```

***Hex your Hash!***

You also need to Hex your hash before you return it

```
var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);
foreach (byte b in hash)
{
     sb.Append(b.ToString("x2")); // x2 is lowercase
}
signature = sb.ToString();
```

Wrap everything into a nice global method with a `SortedList<string,string>` as input, iterate through the values, string them with a `StringBuilder`, MD5 Hash it, and return your signature.

(Yes, a `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` automatically sorts the list as you enter the values on TKey string, which is a requirement in the [API Documentation.](https://developers.payfast.co.za/api#authentication))